# How to extract a specific substring in Java

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a string that I define as

```
String string = "<html><color=black><b><center>Line1</center><center>Line2</center></b></font></html>";
```

that I apply to a JButton to get 2 lines of text on it, and that works perfectly. When I call the JButton.getText() method, it returns the whole string. What I want is to take the string it returns, and get the string "Line1Line2" from it. (So I want to remove all the HTML code and just get the text that appears on the screen.) I have tried using something like

```
if(string.contains("<html>"))
    {
        string.replace("<html>", "");
    }
```

and then doing the same thing for all the other "<(stuff)>", but if I then print the string, I still get the whole thing. I think using regular expressions is a better way than to manually remove all the "<(stuff)>", but I don't know how.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.replace()` doesn't modify the string: a String is immutable. It **returns** a new string where the replacement has been done.

So your code should be

```
if (string.contains("<html>")) {
    string = string.replace("<html>", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks (again)! That's what I needed. That's twice I owe you now :)

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, so `String#replace` does not change the `String` but rather returns the changed `String`.

```
string = string.replace("<html>", "");
```

and so on should do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

`String` also has a `replaceAll()` method.

you could try `string.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");`

Also keep in mind that Strings in java are immutable and this operation will return a new String with your result